# AngularJS: Unhandled Promise rejection: No ErrorHandler. Is platform module (BrowserModule) included?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I made an Angular Project with a menu and added a Grid Tab, because I want to include a Kendo UI Grid in this Angular Project...

I managed to include the tab and all of Its functions - I also got no Errors in my script "says my VS-Code Editor", but when I open the console in my Browser "I've tried chrome and firefox", I get the Error-Message.

> Unhandled Promise rejection: No ErrorHandler. Is platform module (BrowserModule) included? ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: "No ErrorHandler. Is platform module (BrowserModule) included?"

This is the import Part of my app.modules.ts

```
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, ...
```

**Side note:**

If I remove the BrowserModule, I'll still get the same Error 
plus a [WDS] Error...

I got bigger problems to solve and the rest of the Project is working, but I don't know what type of problems I will get, If I won't solve this problem before moving on...

Comment: VS Code shows compile time error and Chrome console is runtime. Don't even bother to compare them. Could you please post your Chrome console error screenshot?